# Trying to reverse the direction of marquee loop javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, marquee

I'm working from [this code](https://codepen.io/pprakash/pen/oNxNeQE?editors=1111) to create  marquee, but I want the marquee to go left-to-right instead of right-to-left. I was able to make that happen but now the text doesn't loop like it did in the original.

Can't figure it out!

This is what I did to make the marquee scroll to the right:

```
function MarqueeOne(selector, speed) {
  const parentSelector = document.querySelector(selector);
  const clone = parentSelector.innerHTML;
  const firstElement = parentSelector.children[0];
  let i = 0;
  console.log(firstElement);
  parentSelector.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', clone);
  parentSelector.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', clone);

  setInterval(function () {
    firstElement.style.marginLeft = `${i}px`;
    if (i > firstElement.clientWidth) {
      i = 0;
    }
    i = i + speed;
  }, 0);
}
```

I just took the - out of the `-${i}px` on line 11. This reverses the direction but now the text just scrolls off of the screen.

here's my CSS:

```
.marquee-one {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
    color: white;
}

.marquee-one h1{
  font-size: 5em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
}
```

any advice on how to make this loop properly?

Comment: Try to set  `i = -firstElement.clientWidth;` instead of 0, in the if statement.

Comment: this didn't work unfortunately :/

Comment: You should not use margin nor left property to create a Marquee. Search instead on how to properly create a marquee scroller using CSS3 transition or animation and transform translate. Also, using a setInterval 0 is a really bad idea.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi i have edited your code and it's slide from left to right. I added **flex-direction** prop as **row-reverse** to css and it works fine. New css style is below.

```js
function Marquee(selector, speed) {
  const parentSelector = document.querySelector(selector);
  const clone = parentSelector.innerHTML;

  parentSelector.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', clone);
  parentSelector.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', clone);
  const firstElement = parentSelector.children[0];
  let i = 0;
  setInterval(function () {
    firstElement.style.marginRight = `-${i}px`;
    if (i > firstElement.clientWidth) {
      i = 0;
    }
    i = i + speed;
  }, 0);
}
window.addEventListener('load', Marquee('.marquee', 0.2))
```

```css
.marquee {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.marquee h1{
  font-size: 5em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-transform: uppercase
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Cemil</title></head>
  <body>
  <div class="marquee">
    <h1>Nepal * Himalayas * Mountains * Everest</h1>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a bad advice (or continuation to OP's original code) to use setInterval 0 and animate using the `margin` property.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i am not saying that this way is correct way. i just fixed the problem

Comment: I know. I don't find this as a quality answer for that specific reason. Seeing OP doing something terribly wrong, and not event pointing that out, or providing a variation that improves on the issue is like throwing a rubber duck and a water gun at a person that's struggling to keep afloat.

Comment: thanks i will think about that in next answers sir

Answer (score -1):

The problem when you remove the minus sign is, even though the movement is in the right direction, it leaves a white space on the left. I propose to fixe that by translating h1

```js
function Marquee(selector, speed) {
  const parentSelector = document.querySelector(selector);
  const clone = parentSelector.innerHTML;
  const firstElement = parentSelector.children[0];
  let i = 0;
  console.log(firstElement);
  parentSelector.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', clone);
  parentSelector.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', clone);

  setInterval(function () {
    firstElement.style.marginLeft = `${i}px`;
    if (i > firstElement.clientWidth) {
      i = 0;
    }
    i = i + speed;
  }, 0);
}

//after window is completed load
//1 class selector for marquee
//2 marquee speed 0.2
window.addEventListener('load', Marquee('.marquee', 0.2))
```

```css
.marquee {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
}

.marquee h1{
  font-size: 5em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  translate: -100% 0; /* I've added this line */
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <h1>Nepal * Himalayas * Mountains * Everest</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: setInterval 0 is a really bad idea. Why not suggest an infinite linear CSS3 transition using translate and keyframes?

Comment: I agree, I only focused on text direction